# Compress four pixels into one

Tags: c#, image-processing, pixel, image-compression

I have a program, where a 32x32 pixels (this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na1Vc.png)) frame slides on an image, and I would show the pixels in the frame on a 16x16 leds matrix, so I have to compress a 2x2 pixels area into only one pixel. How can I do it? I thought that I should calculate the average of R's values, G's values and B's values and use that averages for the pixel.

Comment: You are doing a reduction by 2 in each dimension, so you are compressing a 2x2 area into a single pixel. So, yes, just average them as you say.

Comment: Can you reduce the size from (32x32) to (16x16) using `InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor`?. Maybe using a destination Bitmap with an `PixelFormat` set to an Indexed palette. The "leds" are actually physical "LEDS", lights? Do you have color map constraints?

Comment: This is a very, very common ”problem” so you’ll find lots of resources online. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Algorithms would be a good starting point. I’d be very surprised if C# didn’t already do interpolation out of the box.

Comment: Your image seems to have somewhat similar colored regions. With additional color discretization you can try run-length encoding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).